# Making a table with result of a query php

Tags: php

I want to make a select between 2 dates and then echo the result like in this image[image: the image]

This is my code and I want to update it to just that if someone can help me I'd appreciate.

CODE:

```
<?php
$dataini = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field2']);
            $dataini = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $dataini)));
            $datafim = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field3']);
            $datafim = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datafim)));
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM conteudo where d_datapub between '$dataini' and '$datafim'");
                    $todos = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
                    echo $todos;
?>
```

HTML

```
 <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/pesquisa.css">
    <div class="well-searchbox">
        <form action="" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Portais</label>
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Data Inicio</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" readonly name="field2" id="field2" alt="Data de Nascimento" class="IP_calendar" title="Y/m/d" style="width:200px;" placeholder="Ano-Mes-Dia">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Data Fim</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" readonly name="field3" id="field3" alt="Data de Nascimento" class="IP_calendar" title="Y/m/d" style="width:200px;" placeholder="Ano-Mes-Dia">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-5">
                        <button type="submit" name="contardata" class="btn btn-primary">Contar</button>
                    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Try to make it simple to understand so we can help

Comment: I want to make the select from my database table of how many information I have between 2 dates and then organize it in a table like that

Answer (score 0):

This is an example on how you can `echo` `php` results with `html table`

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Portal</th>
        <th>Results</th>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$dataini = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field2']);
        $dataini = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $dataini)));
        $datafim = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field3']);
        $datafim = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datafim)));
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM conteudo where d_datapub between '$dataini' and '$datafim'");
                $todos = mysqli_num_rows($query); 
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $portalname = $row['portalname'];//name of database table column with the portal name
                $portalresult = $row['portalresult'];

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" .$portalname"</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$portalresult"</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok thanks , but imagine I want to echo the result of that search for each portal

Comment: Use a `while` loop to `mysqli_fetch_assco` of each `row` in you database

Comment: Can u edit your answer to explain me ? thanks and sorry for your wasted time

Comment: portalresult isn't a database field that is the number of rows that the database has between 2 dates

Comment: Then `echo` the `count` which is `$tdos` in that part of the table

Comment: I want the result the number of arrays that contains the portal name between 2 dates im sorry for the bad explanation